# Tomcat Lifecycle Exception

Tags: exception, tomcat, activation

We are facing a weird issue in our production environment. When we start the service agent that hosts our webservices we are getting the below error. The exact EAR file when deployed in other environments is working perfectly fine. Verified the port, it is free, anyways, tried to change the port and checked. Still the same exception persists. There is no webservice security involved here. It's plain SOAP/HTTP.

```
> Activation error with plugin agent
> [BusinessProcesses/AccountDetailService/Services/AccountDetailService.serviceagent]
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.AgentJobCreator.setState(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.resume(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.FTActivator.itsTime(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.util.ReminderQueue.run(Unknown Source) caused by: An IOException occurred while initializing the service
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.serviceAgent.ServiceServiceAgent.activate(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.AgentJobCreator.setState(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.resume(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.FTActivator.itsTime(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.util.ReminderQueue.run(Unknown Source) caused by: com.tibco.plugin.share.http.HttpInitServerIOException
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.bwhttp.HttpDriver.startListening(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.soap.http.SoapHttpTransportApplication.activate(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.impl.DefaultService.activate(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.serviceAgent.ServiceServiceAgent.activate(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.AgentJobCreator.setState(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.resume(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.FTActivator.itsTime(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.util.ReminderQueue.run(Unknown Source) caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardServer[-1]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.bwhttp.tomcat.TomcatServer.startServer(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.bwhttp.HttpDriver.startServer(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.bwhttp.HttpDriver.startListening(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.binding.soap.http.SoapHttpTransportApplication.activate(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.impl.DefaultService.activate(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.bw.service.serviceAgent.ServiceServiceAgent.activate(Unknown
> Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.AgentJobCreator.setState(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.resume(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.JobPool.a(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.core.FTActivator.itsTime(Unknown Source)
>         at com.tibco.pe.util.ReminderQueue.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardService[Tomcat]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 12 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[TomcatEngine-AccountInfoService]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 14 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 16 more
```

Please guide!

Thanks